# Generating piecewise functions in MATLAB R2016A without SMT

Tags: piecewise

Using r2016a without piecewise in the symbolic math toolbox. Hoping to work with the following piecewise, but have failed with various approaches. Thank you in advance for your suggestions.

Function:

```
 (3*x^2)/100 + 30   if x<22.3607    
 x^2/100 + 40       if 22.3607<=x<=109.5445    
 (3*x^2)/400 + 70   if x>109.5445
```

Option 1) SMT would probably allow:

```
y(x) = piecewise([x<22.3607, (3*x^2)/100 + 30], [22.3607<=x<=109.5445, x^2/100 + 40], [x>109.5445, (3*x^2)/400 + 70)]);
```

Result:

> > Undefined function or variable 'piecewise'.

Option 2) Create function:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
function y = y(x)
   if x<=22.3607;
       y = (3*x^2)/100 + 30;
   else if 22.3607<x<=109.5445;
       y = x^2/100 + 40;
   else if 109.5445<x;
       y = (3*x^2)/400 + 70;
       end
       end
   end
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

Result:

> > q_piecewise
> >     Not enough input arguments.

Error in q_piecewise (line 3)
       if x<=22.3607;

Option 3) Use heavyside:

```
y = ['(heaviside(x)-heaviside(x-22.3607))*((3*x^2)/100 + 30) + ' ...
 '(heaviside(x-22.3607)-heaviside(x-109.5445))*(x^2/100 + 40) + ' ...
 '(heaviside(x-109.5445)-heaviside(x-800))*((3*x^2)/400 + 70)'];

yinv = finverse(y,x)
```

Result (trying to compute inverse):

> > yinv =
> >     10.0*(x - 40.0)^(1/2)

I would like to be able to input a value for x into this piecewise equation and receive a value for y. I would ideally like to do this for the inverse of the above piecewise function as well. In addition, I would like to compute the diff() and int(), so I believe a symbolic function would be best suited for this. Thoughts? Thank you!!

- Bryan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Walt Roberson:

There is no MATLAB interface to piecewise before R2016b. It is possible to use evalin(symengine) to construct a piecewise object at the mupad level, but you cannot create a function of it.

```
f = evalin(symengine,'piecewise([x<5,x^2],[x>=5,-x])')
```

You can subs() into f or you can int(f, x)

Constructing the piecewise by way of a program at the MATLAB level requires some non-obvious steps. It would take me a bit of searching to find where I posted the required helper functions...

Found it.

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/309163-can-i-use-numeric-odesolve-as-a-replacement-to-ode45#answer_240756

You would need the helper function that constructs lists, and you would need feval(symengine, 'piecewise',LIST,LIST,...)

whete LIST was constructed by the helper function.

Answer (score 0):

alternatively, From Star Strider:

```
y = @(x) ((3*x.^2)/100 + 30) .* (x<22.3607) +  (x.^2/100 + 40) .* ((22.3607<=x) & (x<=109.5445)) + ((3*x.^2)/400 + 70) .* (x>109.5445);

t = linspace(0, 150, 500);

figure(1)
plot(t, y(t))
grid
xlabel('t')
ylabel('y(t)')
title('Original Fincton')

yi = linspace(min(y(t)), max(y(t)), 20);                    % Interpolate Inverse
ti = interp1(y(t),t, yi, 'linear');

figure(2)
plot(y(t), t)                                               % Plot Inverse
hold on
plot(yi, ti, 'pg', 'MarkerFaceColor','g')                   % Inverse Interpolated Values
hold off
grid
xlabel('y(t)')
ylabel('t')
title('Inverse Function')
```

It takes advantage of logical indexing and then just adding pieces of the vector to create a continuous line.

The inverse works with the interp1 function.